# ${_3F_3}\left({2,a,a\atop 1,1+a,1+a};z\right)=e^z{_3F_3}\left({?,?,?\atop ?,?,?};-z\right)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I'm interested in a transformation of the form
$$
{_3F_3}\left({2,a,a\atop 1,1+a,1+a};z\right)=e^z{_3F_3}\left({?,?,?\atop ?,?,?};-z\right).
$$
Many times, hypergeometric functions of the form ${_nF_n}(z)$ can have a transformation applied to write them in the form of $e^z{_nF_n}(-z)$.  Kummer's transformation is a good example. We have
$$
{_1F_1}\left({a\atop b};z\right)=e^z{_1F_1}\left({b-a\atop b};-z\right).
$$
Examples for ${_2F_2}$ an $_3F_3$ can also be found, for example [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F2/03/02/05/).  I have been unable to find the transformation I'm interested anywhere.  Is there a systematic procedure for finding what I'm looking for?

**Edit:**
[Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704002237) is an example of a full derivation for a special $_2F_2$ function.

**Edit2:**

Using [DLMF 16.5.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2) we can write
$$
{_3F_3}\left({2,a,a\atop 1,1+a,1+a};z\right)=a^2\int_0^1\int_0^1(tu)^{a-1}e^{ztu}(1+ztu)\,\mathrm dt\mathrm du.
$$
This allows us to express the ${_3F_3}$ as a sum of ${_2F_2}$'s as
$$
{_3F_3}\left({2,a,a\atop 1,1+a,1+a};z\right)={_2F_2}\left({a,a\atop 1+a,1+a};z\right)+z\frac{a^2}{(a+1)^2}{_2F_2}\left({1+a,1+a\atop 2+a,2+a};z\right).
$$
Now in terms of ${_2F_2}$ there may be a chance to tease out the $e^z$ term.

Comment: Hypergeometric functions satisfy linear differentials equations with polynomial coefficients. Could try subtstitution & seeing what differential equations are derived ?

Comment: Hi stranger ! The linked paper is interesting.

Comment: (12) from this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348049405_The_Computation_of_a_2F2_Hypergeometric_Function gives us an integral representation that might be useful 
$$\, _2F_2(a,a;a+1,a+1;-x)=\frac{a^2}{x^a} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\gamma(a,xt)}{t} dt $$